# skip authorization for specific controllers using pundit in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I am using rails 4, devise for authentication and Pundit for authorization. I have restricted my application to check for authorization on every controller by below code.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized
  #.....
end
```

However, i want to skip authorization for two specific controllers in my application (they are open to public, users do not need to sign in). How can i achieve it without removing verify_authorized in ApplicationController ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
skip_after_action :verify_authorized
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm working with **Rails 5** and I wanted to ***skip authorization*** in just one action but not the whole controller. So, what you can do according to the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pundit#Ensuring_policies_are_used) is to use `skip_authorization` feature in the controller action as shown below:

```
class Admin::DashboardController < Admin::BaseController
    def index
        @organizers = Organizer.count
        @sponsors = Sponsor.count
        @brochures = Brochure.count

        skip_authorization
    end

    def sponsors_approve
        # some statements...
    end

    def organizers_approve
        # some statements...
    end
end
```

In this controller the only one action to be skipped is `index`, the other ones must be authorized.

I hope it could be useful for somebody else.

Comment: Better use `before_action :skip_authorization, only: :index`, this way it's clear what you're doing and you don't have to copy anything if you decide you wanna do this in any other action as well